# Azure AD configuration for Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory

I tried to integrate Azure AD with a Spring Boot web application, I followed the example from the [Azure's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory) but I encountered an error message: "[invalid_request] AADSTS9000411: The request is not properly formatted. The parameter 'scope' is duplicated...", as shown in the below screenshot.

I can't find any `scope` parameter to figure out why it says is duplicated.

[image]

I have in the `application.properties` file the following setup:

```
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.enabled=true
#Specifies your Active Directory ID:
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-id=...
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.profile.tenant-id=...
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.credential.client-secret=...
```

Does anyone had the same issue?

Comment: here a sample:https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-msal-java-samples/tree/main/4.%20Spring%20Framework%20Web%20App%20Tutorial/1-Authentication/sign-in